# Gerrit change-merged hook not triggered

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to test a gerrit change-merged hook.
It is a python script that i created and is marked executable with a python shebang on top.

But somehow, gerrit does not trigger the change-merged hook even after a change is verified +2ed and merged. It only triggers "patchset-created" and "ref-updated" hooks.

What could be going wrong here? I basically want to open a new gerrit on a different branch after a gerrit is merged on the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check exec and access attributes for your script file